# decode sqldeveloper connection password in nodejs

Tags: node.js, passwords, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm facing the issue how can I decode the SQLdeveloper connection password in node.js.
The issue to me Oracle passwords are periodically changed which breack all my scripts. The only way to get it, is connection list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I found the solution:

```
// deps
var crypto = require('crypto');

// ex: decryptPassword('05ca35ad6f01a2e2135be97c74b669cef7');
function decryptPassword(passwd){
    var buffer_data = new Buffer(passwd, 'hex');
    if(buffer_data[0] != 5){
        throw "the first byte is not 5";
    }
    var buffer_key = buffer_data.slice(1, 9);
    var buffer_passwd = buffer_data.slice(9);
    var iv = new Buffer(8);
    for(var i = 0; i < 8; ++i) iv[i]=0;
    var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('des-cbc', buffer_key, iv);
    var result = decipher.update(buffer_passwd, 'hex');
    result += decipher.final('utf8');
    return result;
}
```